# Open chrome without tabs opening

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome allows to set multiple tabs as home - that is very helpful. But sometimes, one just wants to quickly open a chrome window to quickly google a question, without all preset tabs opening. Is there a command line option to open without opening any preset tabs that could be used to create a second link? So that on my desktop I would have open chrome with hometabs open and open chrome without any tabs open?

Answer (score 1):

- Delete file "Local State" that you can find in C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
- Open Chrome, it will ask if you want to restore previous tabs: DO NOT yet
- Open Chrome Task Manager (More Tools menu)
- Restore previous tabs (History menu)
- Kill the Mo*herfu**er tab that is hijacking your Chrome using Chrome Task Manager

Comment: This answer didn't help exactly, but got me on the right path. In addition to deleting "Local State" I also had to delete "Last Version". Then I could open Chrome, and got the "restore previous tabs?" question. I just said No, and started from scratch.

Comment: Yes, but for me, I never want to lose my previously open tabs, I want to keep them, that is why I prefer to use Chrome's Task Manager to selectively kill only the MF hijacking tab.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: This doesn't work unless you have some tabs open already!**

If you are on Windows 7-8 you can right click on the Chrome icon in the Taskbar and click "New Window"/"New Incognito Window", not sure about Linux or Mac though or older versions of Windows.

I wasn't able to see a command line switch that seemed to match your requirements, had a quick search here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: New Window still opens all tabs. So no good.

Comment: Chrome 47.0.xxxx on Win 10:  Selecting "New Window" from the right-click menu started Chrome with 1 window and an offer to restore all open tabs; closing that popup left one blank window.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, you can...

1. "Force Quit" Chrome/Chromium. (One way is to right/two-finger-click the icon in the App Bar, then hold the alt-key down, choose Force Quit.)
2. You will be asked to report or ignore, just choose ignore.
3. Restart Chrome/Chromium. It will either start with only an empty window, or ask if you want to reopen the previous session.